# Following android tab tutorial, can't find or launch installed app on device or emulator

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-tabhost, android-install-apk

Attempting to follow this project
http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

When I run it, it says everything installs alright but nothing comes up and it's not listed under apps.  I find it under application manager.. What can cause an app to install and not launch?

edit:
Here's my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tabs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity android:name="TabsFragmentActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got a launcher Activity?

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> // this
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Edit:
You did not surround it with an Activity tag, so basically you don't have a launcher Activity, fix it like this:

```
 [...]
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name="TabsFragmentActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
 [...]
```

Comment: I thought this was it?
 <activity android:name="TabsFragmentActivity" >

Comment: So you only have on Activity? I fixed my answer

Comment: Its a tutorial for one activity which has several fragments that you tab through.  I think so, I linked the source code.